# to_char function issue with date passing in the format of 'dd-mon-yyyy'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My query is

`select TO_CHAR('03-JAN-2013', 'D') from dual;`

but an error occured as

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

But when query changed as `select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') from dual;`

Result is right answer 5.

I can't understand why it is behaving like this, please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Oh..! now it is treated as varchar  right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please cast the string to date before selecting.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CAST('03-JAN-2013' AS DATE), 'D') FROM DUAL;
```

OR

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('03-JAN-2013'), 'D') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `'03-JAN-2013'` string literal must be converted to the `date` data type before invoking `TO_CHAR` function:

```
select TO_CHAR(to_date('03-JAN-2013', 'dd-MON-YYYY'), 'D') as res
 from dual

RES
-----
 5
```